# UPDATE SUM of left join table SQL

Tags: sql

**TBLOAN**

```
accountno(varchar(16) | payno(int) | payamount(decimal,16,2) | 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
001                   | 3          | 300                     
002                   | 3          | 300
```

**TBPAY**

```
accountno(varchar(16) | ilno(int) | amount(decimal,16,2) | paydt (datetime)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
001                   | 1          | 100                 | 11-15-2017 
001                   | 2          | 100                 | 11-30-2017
001                   | 3          | 100                 | 12-15-2017
002                   | 1          | 100                 | 11-30-2017
002                   | 2          | 100                 | 12-15-2017
002                   | 3          | 100                 | 12-30-2017
```

My SELECT query is :

```
SELECT MAX(p.ilno),SUM(p.amount),l.accountno,l.payno,l.payamount 
FROM TBLOAN l 
  LEFT JOIN TBPAY p on l.accountno = p.accountno 
where p.paydt <= '11-30-2017' group by l.accountno,l.payno,l.payamount
```

**Result:**

```
p.ilno | p.amount | accountno | payno | payamount
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
2      | 200      | 001       | 2     | 200                             
2      | 200      | 002       | 1     | 100
```

How to update the TBLOAN like this :

```
UPDATE l SET l.payno = MAX(p.ilno), l.payamount = p.SUM(p.amount) 
FROM TBLOAN l 
  LEFT JOIN TBPAY p on l.accountno = p.accountno 
where p.paydt <= '11-30-2017'
```

It says I can't use aggregate in an UPDATE statement.

Comment: Read about [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Your query and the accepted answer are both product specific, but for which product...)

Comment: In standard SQL you can't use `JOIN`  in an `UPDATE` statement. Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I'm using SQL SERVER 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE l SET l.payno = sub.m1, l.payamount = sub.s1 
FROM TBLOAN l 
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(p.ilno) as m1,SUM(p.amount) as s1,l.id 
        FROM TBLOAN l 
            LEFT JOIN TBPAY p on l.accountno = p.accountno 
        where p.paydt <= '11-30-2017'
        GROUP BY l.id) sub ON sub.id=l.id
```

You can add this as a subquery with grouping by id and then join to the TBLOAN